# Options for building a python web based application

Tags: python, web

I am building a simple Python web application and I want it to run stand alone like SABNZBD or Couch Patato. These applications are self contained web applications. What do these products use to serve up the web interface?

The application im building will do a lookup of images albums (folders) and when selected, present it a slide show kind of way. All information is in a XML file, so no database needed.
My goal is to make the application as self contained as possible.

I have looked at Django and it looks a bit daunting and overkill for my application, what are my other options.

Thanks Darrell.

Comment: related: http://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks

Comment: Are you sure you want a web application? Sounds like you are creating a desktop application and Python is compatible with many GUI toolkits. It is bundled with [tk](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tk.html) and is compatible with [GTK](http://www.pygtk.org/), [qt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/) and [wx](http://www.wxpython.org/).

In addition toolkits like [camelot](http://www.python-camelot.com/) make rapid application prototyping quite easy.

Comment: I want the application to be cross platform, and the idea is that it should work on mobile devices as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

why don't you use **flask** in python ?

take a look at this 
  http://flask.pocoo.org/

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Comment: I will try this one. Thanks for all the tips.

Answer (score 10):

There are many options and they're all very easy to pick up in a couple of days. Which one you choose is completely up to you.

Here are a few worth mentioning:

**[Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/): a Python web framework and asynchronous networking library, originally developed at FriendFeed.**

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.write("Hello, world")

application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    application.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

**[Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/): a fast, simple and lightweight WSGI micro web-framework for Python. It is distributed as a single file module and has no dependencies other than the Python Standard Library.**

```
from bottle import route, run, template

@route('/hello/<name>')
def index(name='World'):
    return template('<b>Hello {{name}}</b>!', name=name)

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

**[CherryPy](http://www.cherrypy.org/): A Minimalist Python Web Framework**

```
import cherrypy
class HelloWorld(object):
    def index(self):
        return "Hello World!"
    index.exposed = True

cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

**[Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/): Flask is a microframework for Python based on Werkzeug, Jinja 2 and good intentions.**

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

**[web.py](http://webpy.org/): is a web framework for Python that is as simple as it is powerful.**

```
import web

urls = (
    '/(.*)', 'hello'
)
app = web.application(urls, globals())

class hello:        
    def GET(self, name):
        if not name: 
            name = 'World'
        return 'Hello, ' + name + '!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try something simpler, like [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org), which is just one python file and gives you most of the web handling without unnecessary sophistication:

```
from bottle import route, run, template

@route('/hello/<name>')
def index(name='World'):
    return template('<b>Hello {{name}}</b>!', name=name)

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

Comment: From what I've heard it should also be possible to mount a bottle application under any WSGI handler (such as Apache).  So you should be able to prototype your application using the single Bottle file on your laptop (running it standalone with its own built-in HTTP server code) and then deploy it to your "real" server(s).  Particularly handy for little internal utility applications.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at [web.py](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/tutorial). Here is the Hello World example

```
import web

urls = (
    '/', 'index'
)

class index:
    def GET(self):
        return "Hello, world!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the [Cherrypy](http://cherrypy.org/):

```
import cherrypy
class HelloWorld(object):
    @cherrypy.expose()
    def index(self):
        return "Hello World!"
cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())
```

This is so simple and powerful.I using it for 3 years in my all webapplications.